# Fix vertical aligning for links in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add icons to links in my navigation and I need to use different sizes for them. But when I'm  using different font sizes vertical aligning doesn't work.
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

HTML

```
<nav id="top" class="menu">
<div class="container">
   <div id="top-links" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="dropdown"><a><i class="dif-size">! </i>text</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a>text</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a>text</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu {
  background-color:black;
  color:#ffffff;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}


.dif-size {
  font-size:30px; 
}

.menu a:hover, a:focus{
  background-color:rgba(20, 255, 20, .7) !important;
}
```

Comment: It *is* bottom aligned. Is that not what you want?

Comment: I think I'm understanding correctly. Decrease the line-height of your .dif-size

.dif-size {
font-size: 30px;
line-height: 25px;
}

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is middle alignment rather than bottom

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/r7qea1bm/)

```
.menu li a, .menu li i  {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;

}
```

Comment: On both. `.menu li a, .menu li i  {` See this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/5rzo2o20/

Comment: I tried them all. Sorry, i used "!" for simplicity. This solution works for it, but not for icon font. Example: http://www.bootply.com/4NmX8bEQZ6

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you will have to play with [`vertical-align` css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

When you assign different values for font-size, they naturally occupy different pixel values in that space.If they're all aligned inside the same element they will look like they're in different lines and many times they'll look distorted.

i.e: If you have two icons aligned to top in the same container and give font-size:13px; to the first element and font-size:11px; to the second element, the smallest will look uncentered by one pixel because it is 2px shorter in height. In this case if you give vertical-align:1px; to the second icon it will look centered in relation with the first one.

The distortion is visible if you're using a font-size different and unproportional to the glyph's original drawing size.

Answer (score 0):

Adding line-height property fixed this problem.

```
.menu li a, .menu li i  {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/pax5pUk4Br